# Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: https://downloads.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-8.1.0-all.zip

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, exception, gradle

I am trying to build my app using npm, but i am stuck at this error for hours and i still couldn't figure out why. I tried deleting the gradle-wrapper.properties file, creating a new one. But it still isn't working.

This is my gradle-wrapper.properties

> distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
> distributionPath=wrapper/dists
> zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
> zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
> distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-8.1.0-all.zip

and this is the error i have been getting.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: https://downloads.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-8.1.0-all.zipat java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1993)at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1589)at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:224)at org.gradle.wrapper.Download.downloadInternal(Download.java:58)at org.gradle.wrapper.Download.download(Download.java:44)at org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.java:59)at org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.java:46)at org.gradle.wrapper.ExclusiveFileAccessManager.access(ExclusiveFileAccessManager.java:65)at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.createDist(Install.java:46)at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:126)at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:61)
```

gradle.build

```
apply plugin: "com.android.application"
import 'com.android.build.OutputFile'
project.ext.react = \[
entryFile: "index.js"
\]
apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native/react.gradle"

def enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture = false
def enableProguardInReleaseBuilds = false
android {
compileSdkVersion 33
buildToolsVersion "33.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.timetable"
        minSdkVersion 31
        
        targetSdkVersion 31
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        ndk {
            abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
        }
        configurations.all {
        resolutionStrategy { force 'androidx.work:work-runtime:2.6.0' }
    }
    }
    splits {
        abi {
            reset()
            enable enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture
            universalApk false  
            include "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled enableProguardInReleaseBuilds
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"
        }
    }
    
    applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        variant.outputs.each { output ->
            
            def versionCodes = ["armeabi-v7a":1, "x86":2]
            def abi = output.getFilter(OutputFile.ABI)
            if (abi != null) {  
                output.versionCodeOverride =
                        versionCodes.get(abi) * 1048576 + defaultConfig.versionCode
            }
        }
    }

}

dependencies {
implementation project(':react-native-splash-screen')
implementation project(':react-native-material-kit')
implementation project(':react-native-vector-icons')
implementation project(':react-native-i18n')
implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: \["\*.jar"\])
implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1"
implementation "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"  
def work_version = "2.6.0"

    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.4.2'
    
    }

task copyDownloadableDepsToLibs(type: Copy) {
from configurations.implementation
into 'libs'
}
subprojects { subproject -\>
if(project\['name'\] == 'react-native-geocoder'){
project.configurations { compile { } }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

While you should not use `-all`, but `-bin`, your problem is "8.1.0" vs. "8.1".

Only the hotfix versions are with three digits, the main releases are only with two digits.

Comment: Thank you, This fixed that issue, but it brought up another issue 

Could not find method classpath() for arguments [com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.1.0] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.

I tried changing the version number, but i couldn't get this problem to resolve

Comment: You should not post follow-up questions in comments, but new questions. Also please have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers. But regarding your question, your build script is full of legacy things and bad practices. One of them is, that you apply plugins the legacy way, but do it wrongly. The `classpath` configuration is not a production configuration, but a buildscript configuration, you need to declare that dependency within a `buildscript { ... }` block, or better stop using the legacy way of applying pluigins.